# BLDC Motor and Servo tester Issue

Tags: power-supply, brushless-dc-motor

I have a 12 V DC wall charger. I'm using it to power a 1800Kv bldc motor. The bldc motor is connected to a 30 A ESC and a servo tester. The problem is that when I start rotating the servo tester, the speed initially increases gradually but the motor speed maxes out halfway at at a medium speed and then reduces as I rotate the dial more rather than constantly increasing and reaching its max speed when the servo tester is at its max rotation capability. So the motor can never achieve its highest power. But when I connected a multimeter to the circuit in series to check the current its drawing, the servo tester and motor worked just fine. The motor speed constantly increased as I rotated the servo tester till the end, reaching its highest speed. What is happening? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: This is completely dependent on the software in the ESC.

Comment: you are asking for someone to explain the behavior of an unknown device

Comment: i am asking if someone knows why this cud happen , or what i can do to fix it. i saw some videos of the same BLDC motor working which used the same ESC , so why is mine  doing this. Do i need a higher amp power source or different components ??

Comment: if someone asks you `do I  need a different hammer?`, then what would you say?

Comment: ok so you tell me, what should i do ?? just throw away the project ? cuz nobody else in my house knows the slightest of electronics , that's why i came to stack exchange

Comment: did you connect the multimeter in series with the motor, or the power supply? What happens if you connect it in series with the other? Post a schematic of every connection in each of your setups. A photo might help as well. You're seeing something strange, so maybe what's causing it is something you don't realise the significance of. We need something to go on to help you.

Comment: Contact the vendor of the ESC.

Comment: To help get an answer can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/707802/edit) the question to include links to the datasheets of the bldc motor, ESC, servo tester and 12 V DC wall charger.